# mvc controller list parameter for custom class with custom constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, class, ienumerable

I have this class `UFParameter` with variables `UFType`, `Value` and `FieldNo`.
The `Value` (property that is linked to `ptivate object value` variable) of this class is dynamic, and depends on the `UFType` of the instance.
This is why I need the constructor with all three parameters, and must not have the empty constructor (I tried with empty constructor but then I don't have enough control over what's happening).

MVC's controller's `[HttpGet]` function for searching the database is using a `IEnumerable<UFParameter>` to fill in the query.

**Note** - I'm working with 3rd party API. Their query needs only the combination of `FieldNo` and `Value.ToString()` (a string) to work, but I need to have different types of `Value` property for other stuff with this API.

This `[HttpGet]` function is smart enough to be able to convert the string like this: *searchParameters[0].FieldNo=193&searchParameters[0].Value=jpg&searchParameters[0].Type=0&searchParameters[1].FieldNo=194&searchParameters[1].Value=mini&searchParameters[1].Type=0&searchParameters[2].FieldNo=195&searchParameters[2].Value=8000&searchParameters[2].Type=1* 
 to an `IEnumerable<UFField>`.

Now that I can't leave the `UFParameter` with an empty constructor, how do I convert sutch string to an `IEnumerable` ? (MVC's throwing an error when I don't leave the empty contructor for `UFField`)

Comment: Can you add the Code of your Controller and the Exception Details?

Comment: They are not relevant. The explanation of code I provided is just an example. The jist of it is: how to make MVC's controller's function call the custom class's constructor for each item in list that is provided as a above mentioned like string?

Comment: @Monset You could write a custom model binder which handles the creation of your enumerable... But as it seems, this `UFParamter` is something that is used deeper down in your app (like some kind of business layer). So I would recommend to get your values as provided and map it to your business type yourself.

Comment: @ypsilo0n that is wise. I will try to come up with something with that in mind.. Probably make the `private STRING value` instead of `object`. and then parse it where I need it.... Ill try and report back. Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to pass runtime data through the constructor of services? Just pass the runtime data through methods on your services.

Comment: This question is off-topic without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You need to provide code or this question is likely to be closed.

Comment: I did use as least code I can, I did lay out all information needed for problem to be reproduced. As in 2nd comment, again, the code I typed would just be representation of what I said. Please don't even bother if you can't imagine a simple class with 3 variables based on simple and accurate description provided. Also, @ypsilo0n, this way of thinking made things work, and so the question is answered by providing different approach to the problem. Thanks!